# Unable to lookup transform

Tags: transforms, tf2, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using this code

```
geometry_msgs::PoseStamped current_position()  
{  
        tf::TransformListener my_temp_listener;  
        geometry_msgs::PoseStamped  pose;  
        pose.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();  
        pose.header.frame_id = "/base_link";  
        pose.pose = pose_zero;  
        my_temp_listener.waitForTransform("map", "/base_link", ros::Time(0), ros::Duration(3.0));  
        tf::StampedTransform my_transform;  
        my_temp_listener.lookupTransform("/map","/base_link",ros::Time(0), my_transform);  
        my_temp_listener.transformPose("map", pose, pose);   
        return pose;  
}
```

I get terminate called after throwing an instance of `tf::ExtrapolationException`

```
  what():  Unable to lookup transform, cache is empty, when looking up transform from frame [/base_link] to frame [/map] at runtime.
```

However, looking at the frames using rosrun tf tf_echo /base_link /map I correctly get
At time 1400687504.239

- Translation: `[-8.817, 0.695, 0.000]`
- Rotation:
  - in Quaternion `[0.000, 0.000, 0.097, 0.995]`
  - in RPY `[0.000, -0.000, 0.194]`
  Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/167706/unable-to-lookup-transform/) by [Rahndall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3415/rahndall/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2014-05-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank for the suggestion
I solved in this way and it works, I don't know if it is the best solution

```
geometry_msgs::PoseStamped current_position()  
{ 
        ros::Time now = ros::Time::now();  
        geometry_msgs::PoseStamped  pose;  
        pose.header.stamp = now;  
        pose.header.frame_id = "/base_link";  
        pose.pose = pose_zero;  
        tf::StampedTransform my_transform;

        try {
                mRosTransformListener->waitForTransform("/base_link", "/map", (now+ros::Duration(1.0)), ros::Duration(10.0) );
                mRosTransformListener->lookupTransform("/base_link", "/map", now, my_transform);
        } 
        catch (tf::TransformException ex) { ROS_ERROR("%s",ex.what()); }
        if (mRosTransformListener->frameExists("/map"))
                ROS_INFO ("/map exist");
        if (mRosTransformListener->frameExists("/base_link"))
                ROS_INFO ("/base_link exist");
        try {
                mRosTransformListener->transformPose("/map", pose, pose);
        } 
        catch (tf::TransformException ex) { ROS_ERROR("%s",ex.what()); }       
        ROS_INFO("pose %f %f %f", pose.pose.position.x, pose.pose.position.y, pose.pose.position.z);                
        return pose;
}
```

Thank you again for you support

---

Originally posted by [Rahndall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3415/rahndall/) with karma: 133 on 2014-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to give the listener time to build up it's cache of data. I suggest that you go through the [tf tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials) which cover these sorts of issues.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-05-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1